# Is there a way to store data returned from an observable into a property of a service that can be called by multiple services synchronously?

Tags: angular

Here's what I want. 
Instead of storing token to local storage, I would like to store it into a service, but since getting the token involves getting it from an observable 
I only get `'undefined'` returned, unless the service returns `observable` and then have to subscribe again in every other service that has the first service injected.

> Is there a way to avoid this and get the token synchronously from the
>   service?

Comment: Dont use unrelated tags

Comment: you might want to integrate ng-rx in your project. State management becomes real easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `BehaviorSubject` in your service, you will get both synchronous and asynchronous access to your token, the subject will always give you the last value stored but you can also get a stream using `tokenSubject.asObservable()`.

You can define `get/set` methods for accessing the token synchronously and you can expose a `token$` observable if necessary.

Then you can set this token using `service.set(token)` from anywhere the service is injected, it could be in your `Observable.subscribe()` method that generates your source token.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
    private tokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    token$ = this.tokenSubject.asObservable();

    get(): string {
        return this.tokenSubject .value;
    }

    set(token: string): void {
        this.tokenSubject.next(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model if you're familiar with the MVC the M stands for the model or view model which is essentially a class with properties which you can set , also make it a singelton if you want one instance of it all the time

**Pseudocode**

1. Subscribe the observable in a service
2. Set the property of the
   model
3. In the component get the model object and access its set
   property using getter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `APP_INITIALIZER` to get the token (wherever you get it from) which runs when app is initialized. Here's a simplified example:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyStartupService {

  constructor(...) { }

  get token() {
    return this.token;
  }

  load() {
    // return observable or promise, e.g if a http request
    return this.http.get<any>('url').pipe(
      map((data:any) => this.token = data)
    )
  }
}
```

Mark this service in your app.module:

```ts
export function startupServiceFactory(provider: MyStartupService) {
  return (data) => provider.load();
}
```

and in the app module providers array:

```ts
MyStartupService,
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
  deps: [MyStartupService], // add more dependencies, for example HttpClient
  multi: true
},
```

Just inject the startup service where you want, then call and store your token...

```ts
constructor(private startup: MyStartupService) { }

// ...

this.token = this.startup.token;
```

yaay, now you have the token in a variable :)